# How to perform ldap search using wso2 esb?

Tags: search, ldap, using, wso2-esb

I have written wso2esb configuration to perform "search" in an OpenLDAP server.

Below is my ESB configuration for the API:

```
<api context="/searchLDAP" name="searchLDAP">
        <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/adap/{baseDN}">
            <inSequence>
                <log>
                    <property name="GET" value="searchLDAP"/>
                </log>
                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com:secret"/>
                    <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost:7070/adap/{baseDN}"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
        </resource>
    </api>
```

I have LDAP installed in my local system. I also have ADAP which is configured to call LDAP server.

Here is the configuration to connect to LDAP server.
Base DN : ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
User DN : cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
Password: secret

The code for token Authentication is working fine and a token is being generated.

I have a curl script to test the ESB url:
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8280/searchLDAP/adap/cn=Abcxyz,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

After running it, I don't get any response. No error message in logs as well. 
However my back end URL given below works fine and I can perform search very well.
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:7070/adap/cn=Abcxyz,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

I also tried after hitting the ESB URL directly on browser but no luck. 
Please check if there is something wrong with the API configuration or ESB URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [searchEntry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+CRUD+operations+in+LDAP#WorkingwithCRUDoperationsinLDAP-searchEntry) operation in ldap connector to perform search. You can find the ldap connector at [WSO2 Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/pages/top-assets?q=%22_default%22%3A%22ldap%22).

Comment: You can find the connector with following link. Connectors makes the integrations fast and easy with WSO2 ESB. https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/4ecf8dde-60f3-4e91-ba22-5f49a4e302f4